# Is there any benefit to put a broadcastreceiver in a separate process?

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver

I saw a piece of code, where the broadcastreceiver is declared in a separate process
(android:process=":XXXXXX" in AndroidManifest.xml)

And the corresponding onReceive() code looks like this:

```
startService(new Intent(context, XXXService.class);
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Is there any benefit to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any benefit to do this?

None that I can think of. That code in question should not even work, as AFAIK `startService()` will not have begun by the time the process is killed.